# Avoid Chrome saving .txt and .php files to cache

Tags: javascript, php, web-development-server, txt

I am developing a web page (2075.mooo.com, (it is in Catalan)) where teachers control students' arrivals with an NFC card in an Arduino.

The thing is that I save students' data on .txt files, but Chrome saves those to its cache, and I have to constantly remove the cache files. Is there a way to not let Chrome do that or use another strategy instead of .txt files? Because I cannot say to all teachers and students to remove their chrome cache.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### If using Apache:

Add this to a **.htaccess** file created in the directory you save the .txt files:

```
Header always set Pragma "no-cache"
Header always set Cache-Control "no-store, must-revalidate"
Header always set Expires "0"
```

**OR**

If you have access to httpd.conf, you can add the following to it:

```
<LocationMatch ".*\.txt">
     Header always set Pragma "no-cache"
     Header always set Cache-Control "no-store, must-revalidate"
     Header always set Expires "0"
</LocationMatch>
```

They must clear the cache that they already have in their browser.

Comment: Hi, I use apache2, the first method didn't work. I don't have httpd.conf but apache2.conf, but there's a comment in apache2.conf refering other.conf files, Do I have to write it in apache2.conf?

Comment: @GerardJensonOlmos, yes, you can write it in apache2.conf.

Comment: Sorry, but it did not work. The Apache couldn't run properly. I added your snippet at the end of apache2.config.

Comment: @GerardJensenOlmos, did you enable mod_headers?